# Balancing multiple supply and demand locations in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, distance-matrix, spatial-analysis, network-analysis

I am looking for a way to balance supply and demand with respect to distance, between two vector layers in QGIS.

I have two vector layers 50x50m grid

1. Supply (The red negative values)
2. Demand (The green positive values)

The plan is to develop a map to show arrows with values to indicate where all the positive (green) demand values need to acquire the negative (red) values from supply to `=0`.

***Some Additional Notes:***

- Develop the shortest routes possible
- Cells can be split multiple directions
- Cells can receive units from multiple directions

**Question:** If I want to perform this Network Analysis in QGIS what is the proper terminology for it?

[image: Example Supply and Demand Chart]

Comment: The movement is only possible to the closest(neighbour) cells and in eight directions, is not it?

Comment: unfortunately no, movement would have to skip cells if necessary, for example if a negative value is surrounded by negative values it would need to search the next rind out for a positive cell to supply...

Comment: Can a negative cell value be used more than once?

Comment: A negative cell can be used by multiple positives, but the sum of positive cells demanding from that negative cell can not be greater than the negative value...

Comment: @taras Lets say the movement is only possible to the closest neighbour in eight directions? Is there a possible solution then?